# How to get specific key->value pair from a Map which is inside a List

Tags: scala

More Details to the questions here:

I have List of Maps from which i need to get specific key value pair & then flatten it to just get the list of values.

**Example:**

```
val res0: Seq[Seq[Map[String, Any]]] = 
List(
List(Map(city -> london, country -> uk, zipcode -> 12345)),
List(Map(city -> berlin, country -> germany, zipcode -> 4343), Map(city -> frankfurt, country -> germany, zipcode -> 5344))
)
```

And this is what i want

```
List(List(london), list(berlin, frankfurt))
```

Tried below ways but not able to figure out

```
scala> res0.map(x => x.flatten).foreach(println)
List((city,london), (country,uk), (zipcode,12345))
List((city,berlin), (country,germany), (zipcode,4343), (city,frankfurt), (country,germany), (zipcode,5344))
```

Also if i do something like this below:

```
res0.map(x => x.map(y => println(y)))
Map(city -> london, country -> uk, zipcode -> 12345)
Map(city -> berlin, country -> germany, zipcode -> 4343)
Map(city -> frankfurt, country -> germany, zipcode -> 5344)
```

This is not my expected output as mentioned initially

Comment: Maybe something like this: `data.map(_.flatMap(_.get(key = "city")))`? - BTW, there is something fishy about your data format.

Comment: I second @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez answer.  Perhaps you should post this as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```scala
res0.map(_.flatMap(_.get("city")))
```

Be aware the flatMap implicitly converts `Option` to `List` and fails silently if the key `city` is not in your `Map`.

I would strongly suggest you to encode your maps (which I suspect to come from a json) to a `case class`